# SQL query for two column value print from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Thank in advance for i know my problem definitely is going to resolve here within next few minutes.

i have two tables one for **user** data and other for **request** table. **request** table contains the records of all request given by a user to another user. these user details is carrying by table one **user**.

now need to retrieve data from **request** table with the name of user who sends request and user who receive the request instead of **request_by ID** and **request_to id**

As All of you knows that, i am beginner of MySQL so don't mind on my query as below.

```
select r.*
     , u.user_name as request_by
     , u.user_name as request_to
from req_value r 
left join user u on r.req_to = u.user_id
                 or r.req_by = u.user_id
```

Comment: You need to join the `user` table *twice*: once to obtain the requestor and a second time to obtain the requestee.

Comment: you need to join to the user table twice. also inner join would most likely be more suitable

Comment: please send me syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 `INNER JOIN`s with the `user` table to get `name` for 2 different columns: `req_to` and `req_by`

```
select r.*
     , u1.user_name as request_by
     , u2.user_name as request_to
from req_value r  
join user u1 on r.req_by = u1.user_id
join user u2 on r.req_to = u2.user_id
```